# No notification bar when verifying Careers e-mail

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs, notifications

A small UI omission that bothered me: on Careers, when you click the verify link in your e-mail and a page opens back to the Careers site, there's no actual text on screen that states that the process went fine. The option to verify just disappears.

Can we at least get some kind of notification that says "your e-mail verified okay"?

Answer (score 1):

> Just the option to verify disappears

Right -- if your email is unverified, we'll tell you, otherwise, everything is good.